# Why do the concurrent DB connections see each others uncommitted changes though isolation is set to "read committed"?

Tags: java, transactions, hsqldb, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

I am trying to make a few tests to understand how transaction isolation levels can be used to address the various concurrency concerns. I've started with `TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITED`, but the simplest scenario doesn't behave the way I expect. Here's the code:

```
try(Connection connection1 = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, JDBC_USER, JDBC_PASSWORD)) {
    connection1.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
    connection1.setAutoCommit(false);

    try(Connection connection2 = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, JDBC_USER, JDBC_PASSWORD)) {
        connection2.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
        connection2.setAutoCommit(false);

        assertEquals(0, selectAll(connection1));
        assertEquals(0, selectAll(connection2));

        insertOne(connection1);
        assertEquals(0, selectAll(connection2)); // there is 1 row!
    }
}
```

Here, I set up the 2 concurrent connections, start the transaction in both of them, make the changes in first connection and expect to not see them in the second one. This does not work: the uncommitted changes made in connection 1 are visible to connection 2.

I use HSQLDB 2.3.2 running in embedded mode with in-memory database. Here are the implementations of my selectAll/insert helper methods:

```
private static void initSchema() throws SQLException {
    try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, JDBC_USER, JDBC_PASSWORD)) {
        try (PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(
                "create table Notes(text varchar(256) not null)")) {
            s.executeUpdate();
        }
    }
}

private static int selectAll(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    int count = 0;
    try (PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement("select * from Notes")) {
        s.setQueryTimeout(1);
        try (ResultSet resultSet = s.executeQuery()) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}

private static void insertOne(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    try(PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement("insert into Notes(text) values(?)")) {
        s.setString(1, "hello");
        s.setQueryTimeout(1);
        s.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

The complete test can be found here: https://gist.github.com/loki2302/aad49a5a2c26d5fda2b3

Is something wrong with this code, or does HSQLDB not behave the way it should?

**Update**: after re-reading the wiki, I believe that my idea here is wrong. What I see here is a "phantom read". `READ_COMMITTED` does not guarantee that phantom reads never occur. What I should check instead is, pre-propulating the table with a single row, updating it via `connection1` and making sure that this change is not visible via `connection2` unless the change is committed. Moreover, *it is not guaranteed in general* that this change becomes visible right after the commit: it *may* become visible, but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: What happens if you use a mysql database instead with InnoDB as storage engine?

Comment: It's not a phantom read. Phantom read occurs when two reads in the same transaction return different results in consequence of an insert comitted by another transaction. The code you posted should behave as expected by you...maybe there is something wron with your db configuration.

Comment: It **IS** a phantom read. There are 2 identical queries which I run before and after the insertion, and they provide *different* results. Wiki says: "when, in the course of a transaction, two identical queries are executed, and the collection of rows returned by the second query is different from the first".

Comment: @agori Then please post an answer and explain exactly why this is legal and how to prevent it. This would be very helpful to us :)

Comment: I have tested it with a MySQL InnoDB table and that worked as you would expect your example to work. But the actual question is whether it is ACID compliant behavior and why. So either 1) it does not matter whether the action causing the phantom read has been commited in order to be a legal phantom read OR 2) your entire database is configured not to support transactions in some way

Comment: @loki2302 It seems to me that transactions are not working. It is like you are somehow using autocommit mode. A phantom read requires that the second transaction send a commit statement to the db before the second read of the first transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your in-process database setup is not suitable for the test you are performing.

The alternatives are:

1. Try running a server and repeat your tests with MVCC.
2. Try using a separate thread for each connection with MVCC and in-process database.

When used in-process, like your example, HSQLDB requires each connection to be owned by a separate thread. Otherwise the Java concurrency features will not work.

When run with separate threads, you need to use the MVCC transaction model for this to work. In the default locking mode that you have used, the insert will lock out the other connection until commit.